# [UWP/MVVM]Enable/Disable Button in RadDataGrid Data Template Column that have commands bound to them upon conditions

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have set a bool property and have bound it to the IsEnabled in the xaml but the ICommand CanExecute method overrides the IsEnabled in xaml, so my bool property is ineffective.

When I define the conditions within the CanExecute method in the view model, It either disables all buttons in which the method is bound to, or enables all of them.

Its a grid that displays 3 different buttons for each row, and each button goes to a new xaml screen. If there is no data for the particular condition on the row the button is on then the button needs to be disabled.

How do i go about setting this so that buttons are disabled upon a condition?

Custom Command:

```
public class CustomCommand : ICommand
{

    private Action<object> execute;
    private Predicate<object> canExecute;
    public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;

    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {

        }
        remove
        {

        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        bool b = canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
        return b;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<DataTemplate>
                                <Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM},
                                Path=Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit" Foreground="AliceBlue" />
                                </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

CanExecute in VM

```
 private bool CanGetDetails(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do your conditional statement within the CanExecute function of your custom command, no need for you to bind IsEnabled property with your button that is bound to a command. Here's a sample implementation, hope this helps.

Custom Command:

```
public class CustomCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _action;
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;

    public CustomCommand(Action<T> action, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

As you can see here, I created an object that implements the ICommand interface, this custom command accepts a generic type parameter which is used to evaluate a condition (CanExecute: this tells whether to enable or disable a command (in UI, the button), normally use to check for permissions, and other certain conditions) this parameter is also used to execute the action (Execute: the actual logic/action to be performed), The command contructor accepts delegate parameters that contain signatures for these 2 methods, the caller may choose lambda or standard methods to fillup these parameters.

Sample ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel1: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel1()
        {
            // Test Data.
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
            {
                new ItemViewModel{ Code = "001", Description = "Paint" },
                new ItemViewModel{ Code = "002", Description = "Brush" },
                new ItemViewModel{ Code = "003", Description = "" }
            };

            EditCommand = new CustomCommand<ItemViewModel>(Edit, CanEdit);
        }

        public CustomCommand<ItemViewModel> EditCommand { get; }

        private bool CanEdit(ItemViewModel item)
        {
            return item?.Description != string.Empty;
        }

        private void Edit(ItemViewModel item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Selected Item: {0} - {1}", item.Code, item.Description);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get => _items;
            set
            {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Page x:Name="root"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:vms="using:App1.ViewModels"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vms:ViewModel1 x:Name="Model"/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 15">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, ElementName=root}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this one worked for me perfectly. The way the custom command was set up prior was not working well for the way we are doing things. Could you elaborate on the Command and why you have two of each CanExecute?

Comment: Hi! I cleaned up the code and added some more elaboration about the custom command.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sorry if this is not allowed, but could you upvote my question so that i can further my reputation. Much appreciated if so.

Comment: Could this be done with multiple conditions for one button?

Comment: Yes, if you put all your conditions inside the CanEdit function then return the bool result if or if not the conditions were met.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pick a lot of code from the RelayCommand of MVVMLight. Try to change your event to

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (canExecute != null)
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
        }

        remove
        {
            if (canExecute != null)
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

and add also a function

```
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
```

Then, whatever you put as your Predicate on the command, at the Predicate's boolean setter do:

```
SomeCustomCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you, because i'm sure it works, but the below answer was the one that worked for me.