# Could not pass values from view to viewmodel through commands

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am implementing MVVM pattern for my application. I have my Views, ViewModel, Model and Commands and Converters being implemented. Now I am not able to pass my textboxes values from my datatemplate to my ViewModel through the command binding. I am able to click on the button to attempt the update process but its not able to pass the textboxes value. Are there something i need to change on my command class?

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" x:Name="productionLineConfigDataGrid" Margin="70,0.2,70,0" ItemsSource="{Binding listAllProductionLineConfigs}">
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="ID: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlockLineId" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding ProductionLineId, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Update" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnUpdate_Click" Command="{Binding DataContext.updateProductionLineConfigCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:production_line_config_home}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ProductionLineConfig}"/>
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the method from my ViewModel:

```
public ProductionLineConfig ProductionLineConfig
    {
        get { return productionlineconfig; }

        set
        {
            productionlineconfig = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineConfig");
        }
    }
```

This is the error message i am getting:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ProductionLineConfig' property not found on 'object' ''ProductionLineConfig' (HashCode=47309994)'. BindingExpression:Path=ProductionLineConfig; DataItem='ProductionLineConfig' (HashCode=47309994); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

I have included the image for my application [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzKYy.png)

This is the entire xaml code [here](https://pastebin.com/2AuEatSU) and this is the entire viewmodel code [here](https://pastebin.com/0kDCpb8p)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375875/uwp-mvvmenable-disable-button-in-raddatagrid-data-template-column-that-have-co/52379713?noredirect=1#comment91720911_52379713

Comment: @Mac i believe that didnt worked for my case.

Comment: What is your listAllProductionLineConfigs? is this a list of ProductionLineConfig?

Comment: @Mac yes it lists out all the production line configs in the datagrid

Comment: @Mac please view the image link which i have posted in the question you might a view of what am i doing. The moment i click on the Update button, it will show a messagebox from my view model method where it displays the Line Name, Status and Line ID. But currently, it not getting any values

Comment: I see, hmm.. might be helpful if you could post your entire viewmodel? if it's not that huge, and your entire xaml as well?

Comment: @Mac pls look into my question for the both links on the viewmodel and xaml

Comment: yeah I see how you setup your commad, you need to change it to accept an object from command parameter, copy the command from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375875/uwp-mvvmenable-disable-button-in-raddatagrid-data-template-column-that-have-co/52379713?noredirect=1#comment91720911_52379713 save it to CustomCommand.cs, then you can chat me up

Comment: @Mac you want me to copy the customcommand code from your answer in the link is it?

Comment: @Mac i have already implemented it.

Comment: @Mac do you have skype that we can take it from there?

Comment: you're not eligible for chat yet, let's try this I looked for free online chat http://www.e-chat.co/room/19785698

Comment: Aside from the oter comments and answers, a `<TextBlock/>` is not an input control - the twoway binding makes no sense. You probably meant to use `<TextBox/>` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code source, I made a sample implementation, to achieve your requirement.

Sample VM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp5.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductionLineConfigViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public CustomCommand<ProductionLineConfig> UpdateCommand { get; }

        public ProductionLineConfigViewModel()
        {
            PopulateProductionLineConfigs();
            UpdateCommand = new CustomCommand<ProductionLineConfig>(UpdateConfig, (u) => true);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ProductionLineConfig> _listAllProductionLineConfigs;
        public ObservableCollection<ProductionLineConfig> listAllProductionLineConfigs
        {
            get { return _listAllProductionLineConfigs; }
            set
            {
                _listAllProductionLineConfigs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        //  Call this from constructor.
        private void PopulateProductionLineConfigs()
        {
            listAllProductionLineConfigs = new ObservableCollection<ProductionLineConfig>
            {
                new ProductionLineConfig
                {
                    ProductionLineId = 1,
                    ProductionLineCode = "001",
                    ProductionLineCreatedDate = DateTime.Today.Date,
                    ProductionLineName = "safdsf",
                    ProductionLineStatus = true
                },
                new ProductionLineConfig
                {
                    ProductionLineId = 1,
                    ProductionLineCode = "002",
                    ProductionLineCreatedDate = DateTime.Today.Date,
                    ProductionLineName = "sadfadfsdf",
                    ProductionLineStatus = true
                }
            };
        }

        private void UpdateConfig(ProductionLineConfig config)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Line Name update: " + config.ProductionLineName);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

    public class ProductionLineConfig
    { 
        public int ProductionLineId { get; set; }

        public string ProductionLineCode { get; set; }

        public string ProductionLineName { get; set; }

        public bool ProductionLineStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProductionLineCreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sample XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="Root" x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApp5.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ProductionLineConfigViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid Background="#FF006E8C">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Content="KAD ShopFloor System" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="White"/>
        <Separator Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="White" Margin="0,-35,-0.4,39.2"/>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" x:Name="productionLineConfigDataGrid" Margin="70,0.2,70,0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.listAllProductionLineConfigs, ElementName=Root}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ProductionLineId, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Production Line Code" Binding="{Binding ProductionLineCode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Production Line Name" Binding="{Binding ProductionLineName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding ProductionLineStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created Date" Binding="{Binding ProductionLineCreatedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Padding="10">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stck">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="ID: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlockLineId" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding ProductionLineId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Line Code: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlockLineCode" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding ProductionLineCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Line Name: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <TextBox x:Name="txtLineName" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Text="{Binding ProductionLineName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="Status: " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                    Path=DataContext.Statusstring}" SelectedValue="{Binding ProductionLineStatus, Converter={StaticResource statusToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="cbProductionLineStatus" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>-->
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Update" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateCommand, ElementName=Root}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Sample output:

[image]

[image]

Key changes here,

1. You need to change your list to observable collection
2. Create a custom command that accepts an object, see this post: [[UWP/MVVM]Enable/Disable Button in RadDataGrid Data Template Column that have commands bound to them upon conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375875/uwp-mvvmenable-disable-button-in-raddatagrid-data-template-column-that-have-co/52379713#52379713)
3. Command Parameter should be the iterated item, can be achieve by `CommandParameter={Binding}`
4. In you two way bindings, make sure to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: Can you check this answer? I just noticed the previous answer already talks about the command parameter.

Comment: I dont think the click method would be conflicting.. but anyways i have removed the click method and it still not able to pass the textboxes value to my view model

Answer (score 2):

I'm only going to take a guess at this.

Assuming `ProductionLineConfig` is what you are binding to for `ProductionLineId` in the template. Then you probably are just wanting to pass your binding source as the command parameter

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

When `{Binding}` is empty, it means the Binding is bound to whatever *Source* there is. Which is also just shorthand for...

```
{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}.
```

In turn (if the stars align), then it should be your `ProductionLineConfig`

Comment: You're welcome, I had just started answering when I saw your answer come in. There was nothing more to say.

Comment: @Saruman even i bind it to itself its still not working. Its not able to pass the value to my viewmodel. Maybe you want to look at my Datagrid. I will edit my question once again.