# Telerik UI for UWP RadCalendar How to use commands

Tags: uwp, telerik

I am not sure how to use The RadCalendar comands to update a property in my view model. I follwed this sample from Telreic.

```
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radcalendar/commands/celltap
```

I created a class as stated:

```
  public class CustomCellTapCommand : CalendarCommand
{
    public CustomCellTapCommand()
    {
        Id = CommandId.CellTap;
    }


    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        CalendarCellTapContext ctx = parameter as CalendarCellTapContext;
        var date = ctx.CellModel.Date;
        if (date > DateTime.Now)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        CalendarCellModel context = parameter as CalendarCellModel;

    }
}
```

Heres is the Xaml:

```
<Custom:RadCalendar.Commands>
    <local:CustomCellTapCommand/>
</Custom:RadCalendar.Commands>
```

The CanExecute and Execute methods are being called ok in my custom class. 
How do I call the methods in the ViewModel?

Comment: Can you post your xaml (including the part where you do your namespace declaration for rad and datacontext) and viewmodel (including the part where you want to use your command) codes?

Comment: I presume I just need to add a reference to the view model but that's what I am unsure of how to do. The Execute and can execute are being called fine but how do I reference it to the view model?

Comment: Normally, you create a property of type of that command in you viewmodel, then initialize the value of that property in your viewmodel contructor, you can then bind your command in your xaml provided your data context is your viewmodel like Command={Binding CommandProperty}, haven't used rad controls so im not sure if it's going to be the same implementation, but it's worth the try, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375875/uwp-mvvmenable-disable-button-in-raddatagrid-data-template-column-that-have-co/52379713#52379713

Comment: I did what you advised: I created a CustomCellTapCommand property in my viewmodel and initialised it.The viewmodel is null - when the execute method is called.

Comment: I couldn't make it to work either, I was following this doc from telerik on how to bind the VM commands with RadCalendar, but seems not applicable because it's for Windows 8, gave it a try, but didn't work. https://docs.telerik.com/windows-universal/controls/radcalendar/commands/overview

Comment: Must be a way but there is no sample to follow. Will try something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented a CellTap Command for the Teleric UWP DataGrid. I don't know if it is the correct way please advise if it is not :)
First create a class and call it CellTapCmd:

```
public class CellTapCmd: DataGridCommand
{
    private Object _viewModel;
    public Object viewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel; }
        set
        {
            _viewModel = value;
        }
    }
    public CellTapCmd()
    {
        this.Id = CommandId.CellTap;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var context = parameter as DataGridCellInfo;
        // put your custom logic here
        return true;
    }

    public async override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var context = parameter as DataGridCellInfo;
        // put your custom logic here
       await ((IGridCommand)viewModel).CellTap(context);


    }
}
```

Create an Interface for you ViewModel to implement:

```
interface IGridCommand
{
    Task CellTap(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo);
}
```

Create you ViewModel:

```
  public class AnyViewModel : ViewModelBase,IGridCommand
{
    private DataGridCommand _cellTapCmd;
    public DataGridCommand cellTapCmd
    {
        get { return _cellTapCmd; }
        set
        {
           SetProperty(ref _cellTapCmd,value);
            CellTapCmd cmd = (CellTapCmd)value;
            cmd.viewModel = this;
        }
    }

    public async Task CellTap(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
    {
        //do something amazing here
    }
```

In you xaml:

```
    <telerik:RadDataGrid.Commands>
        <gridCommands:DataGridUserCommand Command="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.cellTapCmd, Mode=TwoWay}" Id="CellTap" />
    </telerik:RadDataGrid.Commands>
```