# WPF Binding Calculated Values

Tags: wpf

I am trying to understand how ValueConverters work. I have three Text Boxes being **txtQty**, **txtPrice** and **txtAmount** representing Qty, Price and Amount respectively and Amount = Qty x Price.

txtQty and txtPrice are unbound controls **whilst txtAmount is bound to a DataTable** in a DataSet.

How can I update the value in txtAmount which is bound to a DataTable using ValueConveter which takes txtQty and txtPrice as input values?

I can easily achieve this in many ways. **But I want to use a ValueConverter for this**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a converter that implements **IMultiValueConverter** to compute for your Price and Qty.

```
public class AmountConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            decimal qty = 0;
            decimal price = 0;

            if (values?.Length < 2)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter should contain 2 values");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[0].ToString()) && !decimal.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out qty))
                throw new ArgumentException("1st value should be decimal.");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[1].ToString()) && !decimal.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out price))
                throw new ArgumentException("2nd value should be decimal.");

            return (qty * price).ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then use **MultiBinding** for your Amount textbox

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAmount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AmountConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="txtQty" Path="Text" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="txtPrice" Path="Text" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

However you may have to do some interactivity with your txtQty and txtPrice to update your viewmodel-bound Amount, you may also need to invoke a command from your vm to accomplish this.

Listing the entire test xaml and viewmodel code...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModelTest />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:AmountConverter x:Key="AmountConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="12 0 0 0" >
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Qty" Margin="0 0 12 0" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtQty" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="50" >
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateAmountCommand, ElementName=root}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txtAmount}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Price" Margin="0 0 12 0" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtPrice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="50" >
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateAmountCommand, ElementName=root}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txtAmount}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Amount" Margin="0 0 12 0" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAmount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AmountConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="txtQty" Path="Text" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="txtPrice" Path="Text" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VM

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApp2.ViewModel
{
public class ViewModelTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModelTest()
        {
            UpdateAmountCommand = new CustomCommand<string>(UpdateAmount, (x) => true);
        }

        private decimal _amount;

        public decimal Amount
        {
            get => _amount;
            set
            {
                if (_amount != value)
                {
                    _amount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public CustomCommand<string> UpdateAmountCommand { get; }

        private void UpdateAmount(string amountText)
        {
            Amount = decimal.Parse(amountText);
            Debug.WriteLine(Amount);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if there's an easier way, this is just on top of my head.

PS: You can copy the **CustomCommand** implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375875/uwp-mvvmenable-disable-button-in-raddatagrid-data-template-column-that-have-co/52379713#52379713).

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that txtAmount is a bound control to a DataTable/Database whilst txtQty and txtPrice are not. If I use multibinding the way you have done then the binding to the Database for txtAmount is broken. That is my problem.

Comment: i see you're not doing mvvm.

Comment: No I am not. How would your solution work in my case?